# Error while uploading image using Multipart

Tags: android

This is my code for uploading image on server,This work fine with other projects but i got error when i am using this code in my project
 //method to get the file path from uri

```
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, 
            null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor.close();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();

        return path;
    }
```

I am using this library for uploading an image :
 compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
  what should i do???

Comment: what error are you getting? show error Log

Comment: from this method you get path right

Comment: Share your stack traces. It will be useful for us to identify the issue and help you out.

Comment: Which type of request you are using Multipart Post or Multipart Put for image uploading..

Comment: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

 at this line :        String paths = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
I have to upload image to server.

Comment: I refer this link :
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/#comment-11923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just got problem because cursor is null at that line.
You have to check null when work with cursor:

```
String path = ""; 
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)); 
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: actually it's not null, it's empty. as per OP comment the error is `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 ... `

Comment: If the path is empty, you need to check before convert to byte[] and pass into multipart. If the path is empty, you get no image. Can you post ur code when you convert path to byte and when you use multipart to post image ?

Comment: I refer this link
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/#comment-11923

Comment: This code works fine on all projects but when i use it on my project i am getting null path.I don't know why?

Comment: I worked on many kind of android device. MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA not return real path for image on all device. Tomorrow i will give you an class that i wrote to get image path. This class work on almost device.